Why are reference types not considered during operator method lookup?
Today I stumbled across the following oddity of Rust's operator/method lookup:
use std::ops::Add;
use std::fmt::Debug;
  
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(i32);

impl Add for &Foo{
    type Output = Foo;
    fn add(self, other: &Foo) -> Foo {
        Foo(self.0 + other.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Works as expected.
    println!("Sum: {:?}", Foo(1).add(&Foo(1)));
    
    // Error. The &Foo::add candidate is not considered.
    println!("Sum: {:?}", Foo(1) + &Foo(1));
}

This was unexpected for me, as I assumed that operators were simply syntactic sugar
for their respective trait method call.
This quirk apparently also leads to many seemingly redundant operator implementations in the standard library and in custom user types.
Especially for custom containers this further worsens the combinatorial explosion
of traits to implement for no (apparent ?) benefit.
Can anybody explain why this is the case?

There are some resources here: Could Rust take an immutable reference of a value automatically? Generally, Rust avoids auto-referencing of values; exceptions like method lookup exist but are not the norm.

a + b gets desugard to std::ops::Add::add(a, b) not a.add(b) (presumably to avoid ambiguity if a has a differeny add method/having to bring Add into scope), so the regular method lookup auto dereferencing rules don't get invoked.

@isaactfa Isn't that isn't 100% precise, there are some differences (that I don't remember off the top of my head).

I'm confused a bit by this question. Are you asking "why" as in "why was the language designed this way"? This is likely to close as opinion-based. Or perhaps you just want a confirmation that the behavior you found (i.e. no autoref of operators) is official?

In rust values are not auto referenced as mentioned by @kmdreko. You are getting an error because Add is implemented for &Foo and not Foo. So if you try to do
use std::ops::Add;
use std::fmt::Debug;
  
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(i32);

impl Add for &Foo {
    type Output = Foo;

    fn add(self, other: &Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self(self.0 + other.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Sum: {:?}", &Foo(1) + &Foo(1)); // Notice the `&` before the first `Foo`
}

It works as expected. playground
Or you could add another Add implementation to Foo. Here you are specifying the Rhs type as &Foo instead of the default Self
use std::ops::Add;
use std::fmt::Debug;
  
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo(i32);

impl Add for &Foo{
    type Output = Foo;

    fn add(self, other: &Foo) -> Self::Output {
        Foo(self.0 + other.0)
    }
}

impl Add<&Foo> for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;

    fn add(self, other: &Foo) -> Self::Output {
        Foo(self.0 + other.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Sum: {:?}", &Foo(1) + &Foo(1));
    println!("Sum: {:?}", Foo(1) + &Foo(1));
}

playground

@RichardNeumann, perhaps because the question asks why, and this answer does not address that at all.

This is a duplicate answer to How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct? but it doesn't answer this question about why it doesn't automatically take the reference.
